# How to host a combined angular 2 and dotnet core site on IIS

Tags: angular, iis, hosting, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building a website and wanted to use angular cli as frontend with .NET core 2 as a REST based backend service. So I created a new angular cli project and then created a webapi project using dotnet cli. I altered the angular.json file to make the output end up in the wwwroot folder of the WebApi project. I have gotten all of this working when I'm debugging and navigating in the localhost site when running `dotnet run` everything works as expected a page can call a REST based controller by going to the adress /api/entities which triggers a get method.

So now comes my problem, since all of this was working so good I wanted to make sure I wouldn't run into any problem when deploying this to the hosting server. The site is hosted by IIS.

I tried to publish the WebApi project `dotnet publish` and copied the resulting files into the sites folder. First it looked like all was good. All the pages was loading correctly but once I reached the page with the call to the REST controller I ended up with a 500 error and no matter how I tried I haven't been able to make this work.

If I only run the angular part of the application with `ng s`
The site is hosted on a different port than when I run the WebApi project with `dotnet run`

Is there some setting I need to make to give the WebApi a specific port so that the Angular part can reach the REST controllers.

Is there something else I need to setup in IIS? I already have the hosting bundle and the application pool is running "No Managed Code"

I'm not asking on other types of hosting the site since my hosting provider is using IIS I'm forced to use that as of now regardless if its good or not.